# Basic Matlab for loop

Tags: matlab

```
A=2;
for x=0:2:4
A=[A, A*x];
end
A
```

I'd appreciate any help! The for loop condition as well as the 3rd line and how they work together I can't quite piece together

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'd just like a simple walkthrough of how this works the answer is A = 2 0 4 0 8 0 16 0

Answer (score 3):

So, here comes the walktrough.

```matlab
A = 2;
```

`A` is an array of length `1`, with `2` as the only element.

```matlab
for x = 0:2:4
```

Have a look at the [Examples](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html#buhafti-2) section of the `for` help. You create an "iteration variable" `x`, which iterates through an array with the values `[0, 2, 4]`. See also the [Examples](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html#bvhfyce) section of the `:` operator help.

```matlab
A = [A, A*x];
```

Concatenate array `A` with the value of `A*x` (multiplying an array with a scalar results in an array of the same length, in which each element is multiplied by the given scalar), and re-assign the result to `A`. See also the help on [Concatenating Matrices](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html#OverviewCreatingAndConcatenatingExample-3).

- Initially, `A = [2]`.
- For `x = 0`: `A = [[2], [2] * 0]`, i.e. `A = [2, 0]`.
- For `x = 2`: `A = [[2, 0], [2, 0] * 2]`, i.e. `A = [2, 0, 4, 0]`.
- For `x = 4`: `A = [[2, 0, 4, 0], [2, 0, 4, 0] * 4]`, i.e. `A = [2, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 16, 0]`.

```matlab
end
```

End of `for` loop.

```matlab
A
```

Output content of `A` by implicitly calling the `display` function by omitting the semicolon at the end of the line, see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/display.html#mw_00466634-ce5b-4002-a259-4837f225b8ff) for explanation.